# Merge/Join one data frame (X) to multiple data frames separately

Tags: r, dataframe

Let us say that we have some data frames named S1,S2,S3... that I want to join independently by column names to dataframe X. This is how they look like:

```
S1 <- data.frame(
  values = c (1:5), 
  numbers = c(11:15))
S1


S2 <- data.frame(
  values = c (1:5), 
  numbers = c(11:15))
S2


S3 <- data.frame(
  values = c (1:5), 
  numbers = c(16:20))
S3
```

#Dataframe X

```
X <- data.frame(
  values = c (26:30), 
  numbers = c(501:505))
X

S1
S2
S3
X
```

Using rbind, it is really easy to merge/join them according to column names. As below:

```
S1_X<- rbind(S1,X)

S1_X


S2_X<- rbind(S2,X)

S2_X


S3_X<- rbind(S3,X)

S3_X
```

Now the problem is that I have 500 plus data frames (S1,S2,S3,S4,S5.....S500) that I want to join to dataframe "X" by any function. For example rbind. Is it possible to use some loop/function for that.

What I have best tried is create a list (nested list of dataframes) that I can later split into individual dataframes:

```
output = lapply(list(S1=S1,S2=S2,S3=S3),rbind,X)
```

The output is what I expected. So it works The only problem is, how do I specify S1 to S500?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I did specify that I have 500 data frames named S1,S2,S3,S4.....S500 that I want to join to data frame X which is a dataframe too. If you will run the codes above you will find out that I tried to make it simple. Thank you!

Comment: @salman1490 I would recommend deleting this question here and reposting on Stack Overflow. It's not really as bioinformatics question and you'll get a much quicker response there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use For Loop here. Here I have created code using your algorithm, first created a list of merged dataframes and then split the list into separate dataframes.

```
S1 <- data.frame(values = c (1:5), numbers = c(11:15))
S2 <- data.frame(values = c (1:5), numbers = c(11:15))
S3 <- data.frame(values = c (1:5), numbers = c(16:20))
#Dataframe X
X <- data.frame(values = c (26:30), numbers = c(501:505))

#defining a NULL object
S=NULL
#creating a list of merged dataframes
for (i in 1:3){
S[i] = list(rbind(get(paste("S",i,sep='')),X))
names(S)[i] = paste("S",i,"_X",sep='')}

#extracting dataframes
for(i in 1:3){
assign(paste("S",i,"_X",sep = ""),S[[i]])
}
```